# Clarification on some mathematics formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-complexity

In the book I am reading (complexity and cryptography by Talbot and Welsh, chapter 4), there is a theorem on  $\textbf{BPP}$ where I don't understand a few steps of its proof, it's totally independent of the concept I am reading, I don't understand the mathematical steps (tagged $(1)$).

> Proof:Suppose $x \in L$ , We need to show that for a suitable choice
>   of $t$, the probability that M rejects $x$ is at most $2^{-p(n)}$ Now
>   M rejects $x$ iff N accepts $x$ at most $t$ times during the $2t + 1$
>   computations.Hence: $$Pr[\text{M rejects  $x$}] \le \sum_{k=0}^t
>  \begin{pmatrix}  2t+1 \\ k \end{pmatrix} (\frac {3}{4})^k (\frac
>  {1}{4})^{2t+1-k} \tag{1}
>          \\\le \frac {(t+1)}{4} \begin{pmatrix}  2t+1 \\ t \end{pmatrix} (\frac {3}{16})^{t}   
>         \\ \le 2^{2t+1} \frac {(t+1)}{4} (\frac {3}{16})^{t}    \le(t+1) (\frac {3}{4})^{t}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> M rejects $x$ iff N accepts $x$ at most $t$ times during the $2t+1$ computations.

It follows from this that

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb P[\text{M rejects }x]&=\Bbb P[\text{N accepts }x\text{ at most }t\text{ times}]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^t\Bbb P[\text{N accepts }x\text{ exactly }k\text{ times}]
\end{align*}$$

Suppose that the probability that $N$ accepts $x$ is $\frac34$. Let $K$ be a particular set of $k$ of the $2t+1$ trials; then the probability that $N$ accepts $x$ on all of the trials in $K$ and does not accept $x$ on any of the remaining trials is

$$\left(\frac34\right)^k\left(\frac14\right)^{2t+1-k}\;.$$

There are $\binom{2t+1}k$ possible sets of $k$ trials, so the probability that $N$ accepts $x$ on exactly $k$ trials is

$$\binom{2t+1}k\left(\frac34\right)^k\left(\frac14\right)^{2t+1-k}\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{2t+1}k\left(\frac34\right)^k\left(\frac14\right)^{2t+1-k}$$

is the probability that $N$ accepts $x$ at most $t$ times.

Without more context I’m not sure why we have only the inequality

$$\Bbb P[\text{M rejects }x]\le\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{2t+1}k\left(\frac34\right)^k\left(\frac14\right)^{2t+1-k}$$

instead of equality, but this should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right after that, it's said that setting $t=8p(n)$, the probability will be less than $2^{-p(n)}$. Could you tell me what is the reason of this claim?

Comment: @Gigili: You’re welcome. $$(8p(n)+1)\left(\frac34\right)^{8p(n)}=\frac{(8p(n)+1)3^{8p(n)}}{2^{15p(n)}} \cdot \frac1{2^{p(n)}}\;,$$ so we’re done if $(8p(n)+1)3^{8p(n)}<2^{15p(n)}$, i.e., if $8p(n)+1<\left(\dfrac{2^{15}}{3^8}\right)^{p(n)}$. It’s not hard to show by induction that this is true for all $p(n)\ge 2$.